# Higher Order Function and Classes in different files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

Currently using react-native and working with High Order functions. I have some presentation components that I am using and I currently have a HOC Container that handles some of the layout properties.

I now realize that I want to have multiple containers that will be different configurations of the same class. For that I made a class in a different file, however the problem is that I can't seem to pass my components to the class with the arrow function. I am pretty sure I am missing something really trivial.

Here is part of the code to understand the problem:

BaseContainer:

```
export default class BaseContainer extends Component {

   render(){
      <Wrapped/>
   }

}
```

HOC Components (Ignore the 2 export default, these are 2 different modules):

```
export default RegularContainer = (Wrapped) => BaseContainer;

export default MessageContainer = (Wrapped) => class extends BaseContainer {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._borderStyle = 'containerLeftBorder';                
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is "Can't find variable: Wrapped" in BaseContainer, which is understandable but I cannot figure out how to pass the Wrapped variable when the class is in another module.

This was working fine if I define the content of the BaseContainer class in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I "solved" it but it seems a little ugly. I'd love to hear some feedback. Otherwise I'll close this as the answer:

```
export default RegularContainer = (Component) => class extends BaseContainer {

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this._Wrapped = Component;             
        }

    }  



export default MessageContainer = (Component) => class extends BaseContainer {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._borderStyle = 'containerLeftBorder';   
        this._Wrapped = Component;             
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is on BaseContainer scope, Wrapped doesn't exists. You need to Import Wrapped or inset it as an class static